# How do I save data within my Google Suite add-on

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps, gsuite-addons

I am making a G-Suite Drive add-on. I have a button that makes a G-sheet. I then can edit that G-sheet from the add-on in a few ways. However, upon reloading the add-on on some later date, I would like it to remember the id of that spreadsheet so it can keep editing it. How do I save the spreadsheet id to my Google Suite add-on?

I don't want to make the G-sheet a certain name then just search the name because users will be able to change the name.

**EDIT:** As seen in comment, the best way to do this is with propertiesService and the fact that it is a G-Suite add-on is irrelevant.

Comment: [tag:gsuite]? Have you looked into propertiesService?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You can use [UserProperties](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service#getuserproperties)

This is allow you to store values, like e.g. a spreadsheetId individually for each user who uses your script.

Sample:

```
var newId = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().copy("new Sheet").getId();
var userProperties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
userProperties.setProperty('sheetId', newId);
```